# Перевод string в другой регистр

Tags: c++, строки

Господа, подскажите, каким образом можно перевести string, к примеру, в верхний регистр.

Comment: Посимвольно, с помощью `toupper`.

Answer (score 2):

Если это ISO `std::string`,   то `std::toupper()` из заголовка `<locale>`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/toupper

Использование cctype  версии черевато тем что оно работает только с ANSI символами, для расширенной кодировки или многобайтовых символов надо указывать локаль.

В boost есть функция работающая со строками.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (char& c : str)
    c = toupper(c);
```

Comment: Работатет только с ANSI

Comment: Лучше так: `c = toupper((unsigned char)c);` Тогда не будет неопределенного поведения на символах с отрицательными номерами.